# Includes not working after AJAX navigation

Tags: php, jquery, include

So here's my predicament. I have several includes on my home page of my website, and they work on initial load. But, if you navigate away from the home page and then come back, the includes are broken. You can [see it live here](http://www.sheekssoftwaresolutions.com/testing/). The following code is involved.

Includes on the Home page:

```
<? include("packages/blog/s3blog.class.php"); ?>
<? include("packages/core/s3core.class.php"); ?>
<? include("packages/core/s3data.class.php"); ?>
```

Home Page location on index structure:

```
<div class="row" id="content">  
    <?
    if($_SESSION['auth'] == 1) {
            include("packages/Blog/manage.php");
    }
    elseif(isset($_GET['page'])) {
        include("pages/".$_GET['page'].".php");
    }
    else {
        include("pages/home.php");
    }
    ?>
    <div class="row-end"></div>
</div>
```

Script used to load pages on navigation click:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.js-ajax').click( function( event ) {
        set_ajax_link( $(this), event );
    });
});
function set_ajax_link( el, event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = el.attr("href");
    load_page_content( url );
}
function load_page_content( url ){
    $("#content").load( url, { 'ajax': 'true' }, function(){
        $('#content a.js-ajax').click( function( event ) {
            set_ajax_link( $(this), event );
        });
    });
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: short tag is not a good option using `<?php ?>` will be better approach imho

Comment: I chose my host specifically because they support the short tag, it's cleaner imho. But thanks for the feed back. I do code my client sites with the extended tag.

Comment: I don't think the includes should break simply because you are going back to the page. The PHP is server side, and wouldn't be affected by the client. What do you mean when you say it's broken? You get PHP errors, or your navigation stops functioning? If it's the latter, then it's a JS issue.

Comment: check `if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
}`

Comment: I know the files are there, what I'm wondering is if the return to the page is causing the PHP errors that are being thrown. Is it possible that the context the page is being referenced from is changing? Maybe if I use absolute paths...

Comment: Also, the error can be seen by following the link in the first paragraph of the original post.

Comment: http://www.sheekssoftwaresolutions.com/testing/pages/home.php it is not about ajax or something else, seems `packages/` directory in the parent dir , not in `pages/`

Comment: Sorry, @eicto, could you clarify? packages/ and pages/ are both on the root dir. The code is designed (as far as I can tell) to work with that.

Comment: home.php is under pages directory, and you have no include paths set to testing directory. that causes the problem, you can fix it several ways, I prefer mod_rewrite and create pages.php whcuh will include correct page, and set include_path to cwd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create pages.php in testing

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(__FILE__));
$page=basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URL'],'php');
include('pages/'.$page.".php");
```

in .htaccess in testing dir (in case of apache)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^testing/pages/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* pages.php [L]
```

not teseted, but i hope you got the idea.